# Refresh converted bindings in WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a ListView with a GridView (multiple columns) layout. Some column have converters which uses the current locale to prettify numbers, turn unix timestamps into datetime strings, or just translate an enum to a localized description of it.

The locale can be changed during runtime, so I need a way to rerun these converters as that happens. Note that the value itself of the binding has not changed, but the output of the converter may be different with a different locale.

What is the best way to do so? I don't want to iterate the whole collection of every affected list and call OnPropertyChanged. Is there a way to either force the ListView to refresh every binding, or just the bindings of some columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyListView.ItemsSource);
view.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the ListView to update the ItemsSource binding with the following:

```
lview.GetBindingExpression(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Using this same syntax, you could certainly get more specific, and force an update only on the bindings for specific columns, but depending on the number of rows in your ListView, you may not see a performance difference.

Comment: GetBindingExpression returns null for me. Could it be because I don't bind ItemsSouce?

Comment: Yes, the parameter to `GetBindingExpression` will need to be a property that has a binding.  So without seeing your xaml, I can't say exactly what it will look like, but this method will force a specific binding to update.

Comment: I was looking for updating the bindings on the objects of the source collection, not the collection itself.